# Override "Processing" in ZK

Tags: zk, zul

```
<?page id="p" title="Data Profiling Home" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
    <zk>
        <button label="Procesing" onClick="Clients.showBusy(null)"></button>    
    </zk>
```

OnClick of button I see this :

[image]

I want to Override the Processing widget so that I can acheive this. [image]

I have searched, in ZK documentation but din't find any help, have any one tried this earlier or any hint,link or reference, can this be acheived In ZK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
<zk>
    <button label="busy">
        <attribute name="onClick">
            busyWin.doModal();
            Div div = busyWin.getFellow("div");
            Clients.showBusy(div, null);
        </attribute>
    </button>
    <window id="busyWin" visible="false" position="center"
        border="normal" title="busy..." xmlns:w="client">
        <attribute w:name="bind_">
            function (desktop, skipper, after) {
                this.$bind_(desktop, skipper, after);
                if (this._drag)
                    this._drag.opts.ignoredrag = true; // prevent dragging
            }
        </attribute>
        <hbox>
            <div id="div" height="30px" width="30px" style="color: transparent;">a</div>
            <button label="abort">
                <attribute name="onClick">
                    Clients.clearBusy(div);
                    busyWin.setMode("embedded");
                    busyWin.setVisible(false);
                </attribute>
            </button>
        </hbox>
    </window> 
</zk>
```

Edit:
The new sample

```
    <zk>
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
        function showBusy () {
            // show busy mask
            zAu.cmd0.showBusy('Loading...');
            // move abort button under busy message
            jq('.z-loading')[0].appendChild(jq('$abortButton')[0]);
        }
        function clearBusy () {
            // move abort button back under abort div
            jq('$abortDiv')[0].appendChild(jq('$abortButton')[0]);
            // clear busy mask
            zAu.cmd0.clearBusy(null);
        }
    ]]></script>
    <zscript><![CDATA[
        class AbortableRunnable implements Runnable {
            boolean aborted = false;
            int i = 0;
            public void run () {
                while (true) {
                    // do somoething
                    i++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    // finish
                    if (i == 5 || aborted)
                        break;
                }
            }
            public void abort () {
                aborted = true;
            }
            public int getI () {
                return i;
            }
        }
        AbortableRunnable ar = new AbortableRunnable();

        void start () {
            // start
            System.out.println("started");
            new Thread(ar).start();
        }
        void abort () {
            // abort
            System.out.println("aborted");
            ar.abort();
            // reset
            ar = new AbortableRunnable();
        }
        void finish () {
            // finish
            System.out.println("finished");
            // reset
            ar = new AbortableRunnable();
        }
    ]]></zscript>
    <!-- abort div to keep the abort button,
        display outside the screen -->
    <div id="abortDiv" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px">
        <button id="abortButton" label="abort">
            <attribute name="onClick">
                // abort the running process
                abort();
                // stop the checking timer
                checkTimer.stop();
                // move self element back to abort div
                // and clear the busy mask
                Clients.evalJavaScript("clearBusy();");
            </attribute>
        </button>
    </div>
    <button label="do something long">
        <attribute name="onClick">
            // start to run the process
            start();
            // start the checking timer
            checkTimer.start();
            // show busy mask and move
            // the element of abort button under busy message
            Clients.evalJavaScript("showBusy();");
        </attribute>
    </button>
    <timer id="checkTimer" running="false" repeats="true" delay="1000">
        <attribute name="onTimer">
            // check whether it is finished
            // similar to the abort part
            if (ar.getI() == 5) {
                finish();
                self.stop();
                Clients.evalJavaScript("clearBusy();");
            }
        </attribute>
    </timer>
</zk>
```

Regards,

Ben

Comment: Hi, thanks this worked!! but I need a way to Override default processing of ZK. Is it possible??

Comment: What is the goal of the 'override'? Change the style or action? Could you describe in more detail?

Comment: I want it to Override in such a way that I can add an 'Abort' button below processing.

Comment: You can try handle the busy mask and abort button by Client Side Programming, please refer to the new sample (added to previous post)